# How to set DataGridViewCell.Value with Option Strict On

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, option-strict

How to test for DataGridViewCell.Value with Option Strict On?

```
If DataGridViewCell.Value = "some value" then
```

Gives the error:

```
Option Strict On disallows operands of type Object for operator '='. Use the 'Is' operator to test for object identity.
```

**EDIT:**

The Solution is:

```
If DataGridViewCell.Value.ToString = "some value" then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message doesn't match your code snippet, that error can't be generated by an assignment.  Being forced to guess, use the ToString() method:

```
 If DataGridViewCell.Value.ToString() = "some value" Then
```

Or use the CStr() operator, that's more VB-ish.